# What can I do If my answer is not accepted even if every sign indicates it is good?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

First of all I have no problem when my answer is not accepted, I can always be wrong, but there are cases when I must think I really answered correctly and noone else answered. I put in lot of details, received upvotes, but still the answer is not accepted. In these cases is there any polite way to remember the question owner to respond (either to accept or ask further)

Comment: I'm 100% sure that this is a duplicate, but I just can't find the question...Anyway, it's dangerous to go alone, take these: [Do you feel dirty if you nudge new users to accept your answer when they indicate you've answered their question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/) [Force Accepted Answers on Questions by Inactive Users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8692/) [How do you react to an apparently dis-interested questioner?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234/)

Comment: And [What happens if you answered a question, questioner says thanks, but didn't accept your answer as correct?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109773/what-happens-if-you-answered-a-question-questioner-says-thanks-but-didnt-acce)

Comment: thanks for all these links, it clearly shows I failed to find the questions about the same issue :) the question you posted is quite nice to read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234/how-do-you-react-to-an-apparently-dis-interested-questioner

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two options:

- Leave a comment, possibly linking to [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if the user is new and might not be aware of the details of how the site works.
- Do nothing.

If you go with the comment, make sure it is polite. If the user is not a brand new user, the comment is most likely useless so you should not post it.

Remember that while your answer might be technically correct, well detailed, compliant with best practices, etc. it still might not be the answer the poster is looking for.

You can't force anyone to accept your answer, that's optional and up to the asker to decide.

Comment: thanks I think I will do that and try to not waste too much of my time thinking about this issue